# How do I refer to a typedef in a header file?

Tags: c, header, typedef

I have a source file where a typedef struct is defined:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct node *next;
} *Node;
```

In this module, there are some functions that operate on a Node and have Node as return type. What am I supposed to write in the header file for this typedef?

Is it correct to write just

```
typedef *Node;
```

in the header?

Comment: why don't you write the whole structure in your header file itself..and use `*Node` in your source file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use:

```
typedef struct node * Node;
```

But I would advise against hiding the pointer in type declaration. It is more informative to have that information in variable declaration.

**module.c:**

```
#include "module.h"
struct node {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

**module.h:**

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

**variable declaration for pointer somewhere:**

```
#include "module.h"
Node * myNode; // We don't need to know the whole type when declaring pointer
```

Comment: Or `typedef struct node node;` and be rid of the caps weirdness.

Comment: @Potatoswatter True. I just didn't wan't to confuse him/her by changing his/her naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration

```
typedef *Node;
```

is invalid. It's missing the type. A good way to look at `typedef` is to remember it is just a storage class specifier, thus, it works like any other declarations. If you want to create an alias `Node` for the type `struct node *`, just declare a node pointer and name it `Node`:

`struct node *Node;`

And now prepend a `typedef` keyword:

`typedef struct node *Node;`

In general, to create an alias for a type, you just declare a variable of that type with the same name as the alias name you wish, and then prepend a `typedef` keyword. Even complicated `typedef` declarations can be easily approached like this.

So, `typedef *Node;` is invalid, it's like writing just `j;` without actually specifying its type.

Now, you can't `typedef` something twice. Either you will have to take the `typedef` out of `struct node` declaration and move it to the header file, or you move the whole `typedef` + structure declaration to the header file. The former solution is generally what you want, since it allows you to have some information hiding. So, my suggestion is to write this in the header file:

```
typedef struct node *Node_ptr;
```

And keep this in the source file:

```
struct node {
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Note that I created the alias `Node_ptr`, not `Node`. This is good practice, to convey the idea that `Node_ptr` is a pointer.